# How do you fix the inertial tensor if the values are all 0 (solidworks to urdf plugin)?

Tags: urdf, plugin, solidworks, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I created a basic assembly in solidworks, and began the export process using sw2urdf by following the WPI Solidworks to Gazebo tutorial. However, I ran into an issue where the inertia tensor keeps being generated as 0 for during the export process, and I don't know why! I've ensured that the parts have had a material set, and when I export a part individually as a link, it has a moment of inertia.

Right now, I'm literally just testing a single joint configuration, essentially a narrow cylinder connected to a block (the base link). I set the respective coordinate systems to be the origin of both parts, and I've created the axis by using the default plane intersections (so I've specified the coordinate system, the axis, and the joint type). Does anyone have any ideas? Also, I used the scale feature to increase the part's size by 100x. The mass properties have updated, so I don't think that's the issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287327/how-do-you-fix-the-inertial-tensor-if-the-values-are-all-0-(solidworks-to-urdf-plugin)?/) by [tzahroof](https://answers.ros.org/users/34451/tzahroof/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think your robot is very small , your may have used millmeter, gram, second unit in sw. sw2urdf plugin exports all the units is mks unit, as a ressult if the model is very small or say the intertia tensor values are very small than as i've seen the plugin calculated them as zero since the vale is very small.
u can use evalute->mass property to calulate those values and than convert it to mks units and than put it manually while exporting to urdf.

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2018-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1